# Why does Solr ClientUtils::escapeQueryChars escape spaces

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Solr query has some special chars that need to be escaped, [+-&|!(){}[]^"~*?:/](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-EscapingSpecialCharacters).

SolrJ provides a utility method [ClientUtils::escapeQueryChars](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.java#L146) which escapes more chars, including `;` and `white spaces`.

It caused a bug in my application when the search term contains space, like `foo bar`, which was turned into `foo\ bar` by `ClientUtils::escapeQueryChars`. My solution is to split the search term, escape each term and joining them with `AND` or `OR`.

But it's still a pain to write extra code just to handle handle space.

Is there any special reason that `space` and `;` are also escaped by this utility method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Solr (and Lucene) the characters can have different meanings in query syntax depending from what [query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Syntax+and+Parsing) you're using (for example standard, dismax, edismax, etc.).

So when and what escape depends from which query parser you're using and which query you're trying to do. I know this seems too broad as answer but I'll add an example to make the things more clear.

For example, let's try to use `edismax` as query parser and have a document with a field named `tv_display` of type `string`.

If you write:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/buybox/select?q=tv_display:Full HD
```

edismax will convert the query in `+tv_display:Full +tv_display:HD`.

In this way you'll never find the documents where `tv_display` is `Full HD` but all the documents where `tv_display` is `Full` and/or `HD` (and/or depends by your `mm` configuration).

`ClientUtils::escapeQueryChars` will convert `Full HD` in `Full\ HD`:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/buybox/select?q=tv_display:Full\ HD
```

So edismax takes the entire string as a single token and only in this way will be returned all the documents where `tv_display` has `Full HD`.

In conclusion `ClientUtils::escapeQueryChars` escape all possible characters (spaces and semicolons included) that can be misunderstood by a query parser.

Comment: `by attrid_340` I guess you mean `tv_display` ? I always use tv_display:"Full HD" to search a phrase, as suggested by [Solr quick start](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/quickstart.html#phrase-search). I tried `foo\ bar`, it also gave me `foo xx bar` in the result. So I guess using slash is not an appropriate way to search phrase ? But it indeed constraint the search field for both words.

Comment: @ray sorry for that, it was a typo. Yep, I was referring to the field `tv_display`.

Comment: Regarding the behaviour you're experiencing, you should post the `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` and the exact query. The right thing to do is create a new question.

Comment: It turns out that my bug was caused by the schema file. For the field I'm working on, it uses WhitespaceTokenizer for the index analyzer, but KeywordTokenizer for the query analyzer. It's a little odd, because white spaces are gone, and searching phrase will never show anything.

Comment: I suggest to fix the query analyzer into a `WhitespaceTokenizer` too.